# how to setup one or two tables where data is similar but used for different purposes

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-studio

I am creating a dictionary app, using Room persistence and MVVM, where there can be words, synonyms, antonyms, and homonyms.  The synonyms, antonyms, and homonyms tables can contains all or some of the same words in the words table.

So, in the example below, "word" in the Word table and "synonym" in the Synonym table can be the exact same values.  This would also go for each of the other 2 tables (antonyms and homonyms [words with same spelling and different meanings]).

```
      Join method                            Self-Join
+---------------------+               +---------------------+
|         Word        |               |         Word        |
+---------------------+               +---------------------+
| PK      word        |               | PK      word        |
+---------------------+               | FK     synonym      |
                                      | FK    antonym       |
+---------------------+               | FK     homonym      |
|         Join        |               +---------------------+
+---------------------+
| FK      word        |
| FK     synonym      |
+---------------------+

+---------------------+
|        Synonym      |
+---------------------+
| PK     synonym      |
+---------------------+
```

I considered using a self-join (not sure if the above is possible), but there can be a M:N relationship between the words and the other 3 tables.

If i create a M:N join for each of the 3 tables with the word table, I will have a lot of duplicate "words" in all 4 tables.  If the data was different, it would be a no brainer, but the data is the same, so I thought I would ask to see if the JOIN this is the way I should do this? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange data model.  I would expect:

```
words
    word_id primary key
```

Then three additional tables:

```
synonyms
    word_id foreign key
    synonym_word_id foreign key

antonyms
    word_id foreign key
    antonyms_word_id foreign key

homonyms
    word_id foreign key
    homonyms_word_id foreign key
```

You could also implement this as one table with a "type" column.

Comment: So, basically a join table for each of the 3 tables (synonyms, antonyms, and homonyms), right? Wasn't quite sure how to word the question.  What I basically want to do is display a list of the 3 other tables with the word, if present.  User will add them as they want to.

Comment: @MichaelScottMartens . . . Yes, a separate table for each of the relationships.